# ASP .Net User control error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We are using asp .Net with C#. I have page(.aspx) consist of multiple Web User Controls(.ascx)

I would like to have an error handling machanism in such a way that if there is any exception in one of the user control, asp .net should show some friendly error message on a control. All other control should render as expected.

Is there any way this can be done without putting place holder on each control which you show/hide in case of exception?

Comment: When does the exception typically occur?  I would try and make each user control handle it internally, not globally.

Comment: Exception will typically occure within a user control(For e.g. some database connection error, type casting error etc..).

Comment: You should then wrap the database calls and casting operations in a try/catch, all of this should be done within the user control.  When I program, I tend to only catch exceptions that are possible to handle, critical things I just let the app fail.

Comment: What type of error handling are you referring to?  Validating user input?  Handling server errors?  Client side errors?

Comment: yes i do understand that. But i am looking for some generic solution. I have over 30 user controls, so i am trying to avoid making changes at every control level.

Comment: @Matthew this works for testing, but you still don't want to show clients the webpage error as it gives away vital information (such as stacktrace) about your website that a malicious user might take advantage of.

Comment: You can setup error handling in your web.config file, locally you will see stack trace, through the internet you will see an error page of your choosing.

Comment: Gotcha, I must have misunderstood what you were suggesting

Comment: @JG in SD. I am looking for handling server errors. My goal here is in case one user control has an error, it should not bring page down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this.

An abstract base class with an abstract OnLoad() that each UserControl has to implement.  You can use this same model for any event that you want to have shared error handling.

```
public abstract class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OnLoad();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Custom error handling here
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnLoad();
}

public class MyUserControl: BaseUserControl
{
    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        //My normal load event handling here
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in the case on general events, but what about click events and other events raised by controls?

Answer (score 1):

1) In app_code, create a class MyPage.cs that inherits Page

```
class MyPage : Page { }
```

2) Change the inherits of your pages to MyPage.

```
public partial class _Default : MyPage { ...
```

There's an attribute in the web.config you can use to change it if you want

3) Back to MyPage.cs, add the generic error handler of all pages

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
    /* here you can intercept the error and show the controls that you want */
    base.OnError(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are using Content Management System call Sitecore. I have a page and controls(.ascx) are added dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

First create a base user controlclass which overrides default onerror event.

```
 public class MyControlClass:UserControl
        {

            protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
            {
                //here you sould add your friendly msg implementation



                //base.OnError(e); here should remain commented
            }
        }
```

Then you can create your user controls:

```
public class Control1:MyControlClass
    {
        // ....
        // ....
    }
```

So, if any control creates an exception , the rest will keep on working.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it will not work, as control will never raise OnError(), look at blog:  http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2003/06/16/8748.aspx